# RobotFramework - keyword assign multiple variables, how to execute it only if condition?

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, keyword, robotframework

I have a Keyword that returns multiple values, reading from a file. I use it to set some variables like this:

```
${A}    ${B}    ${C}    ${D}    ${E}    ObtainVariablesKeyword
```

Where `ObtainVariablesKeyword` has some code and finally:

```
[Return]  ${A}    ${B}    ${C}    ${D}    ${E}
```

The thing is sometimes data is not in a file, instead user write it., So i'd like to run first example row only IF CONDITION.

Does anybody know how?

`Run Keyword If CONDITION KEYWORD` does not allow to put variables after condition, because it waits for a keyword.

Comment: what do you mean by user writes it?  Is this just some of the variables returned or all of them?

What do you use to determine if you're getting user input or being read from a file?

Do you just need some flag to say whether its user input or not, then saw Run Keyword If   ${flag}=${TRUE}?

Comment: Would `Set Variable If` help you?

Comment: Ty alex for your response. Thats the point, how to execute the keyword in that case. Example: <code> Run Keyword If ${flag}=${TRUE} ${A}    ${B}    ${C}    ${D}    ${E}    ObtainVariablesKeyword </code> dont work cause run keyword expects the name of the keyword right after condition, and there i need to put variables to be assigned by returned values of the keyword

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to create another keyword:

```
AssignValues
    ${A}    ${B}    ${C}    ${D}    ${E}    ObtainVariablesKeyword
```

And then call this keyword after `Run Keyword If`:

`Run Keyword if '${flag}'= 'TRUE' AssignValues`